# Change date format in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, jquery, date, asp.net-core, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to change the default date format (`mm/dd/yyyy`) in my ASP.NET Core application. I am using bootstrap date-picker for better user experiences.

But when I change the format to `dd/mm/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yy` using jQuery, it saves `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000` in the database if the day value is greater than 12.

Is there any way to fix this using globalization and culture, as we did in `Global.asax` file in ASP.NET ?

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Please share your code so it will easy to solve it

Comment: If possible, could you please show us the code you use to change the date format? Please share which date value you pass to that code and what result you get after changing the format? Have you set any date format for the date field in your database? Try to manually add one record to the database and see whether it gets inserted as it is or it gets converted to any other format? You could print the values in the console to see at which point it converted to the improper format.